# Image picked from gallery is wrongly oriented

Tags: android

After calling gallery intent and getting the image URI in `onActivityResult()`

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
String filePath;
try {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri,
            projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);;
} catch (Exception e) {
}

File imageFile = new File(filePath);
Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But the image in the imageView is rotated 90 degree. I even sent the image as a file to a web server and that's rotated too.

So, I tried checking for the Exif details,

```
//getOutputMediaFile() just returns a filepath to store image in my app folder
String newFilePath = getOutputMediaFile();
//800 is  the desired width and height
Bitmap photo = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(filePath, 800, 800);
//reduce the size of the image and store it in a new file ie.. newFilePath
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFilePath);
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(newFilePath);
int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);

//If rotation is required
if (rotation != 0) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
    File imageFile = new File(newFilePath);
    //get the same image
    Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    //rotate it
    Bitmap adjustedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    //and save in the same file
    FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(newFilePath);
    adjustedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,out2);
}
```

**decodeSampledBitmapFromFile()**

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
    }
    int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;
    if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
    }
    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```

**decodeFile()**

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {

    IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 800;
    Bitmap b = null;
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        File f = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
        fis.close();

        int scale = 1;
        if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale = (int) Math.pow(
                    2,
                    (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                            / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth))
                            / Math.log(0.5)));
        }
        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return b;
}
```

The code never goes inside `if(rotation != 0f){}`. Which means the image Orientation is proper, then why the file I get or the Bitmap I get are rotated. What am I missing?

Comment: why are you comparing a int with a float ?

Comment: My bad. But I always checked the rotation value in logs. Its always 0.

Comment: It could be some vendors bug or an android bug

Comment: But I see proper orientation on other apps which allow the same `select from gallery` functionality

Comment: can you try to read exit from filePath instead that from newFilePath?

Comment: Yeah even that gave same result for rotation i.e 0

Comment: then I have not clues